# how to create several buttons dynamically in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here id my code. I want to append 4 buttons inside the specific div. In the other words, I want to put these 4 buttons inside ''. Now it works but they are not inside the div.

> getmyItems function is a function that contains an array of information like: title, description , age ,... .

Help

```
getmyItems(param, function(data) {
var mtItem = JSON.stringify(data);
myItem = JSON.parse(mtItem);
var Item = document.getElementById('myItems');
for (var i = 0; i < myItem.results.length; i++) {
var buffer = "";
buffer += '<div class="act-time">';
buffer += '<div class="activity-body act-in">';
buffer += '<span class="arrow"></span>';
buffer += '<div class="text">';
buffer += '<p class="attribution">';
buffer += '<a href="#">'+myItem.results[i].title+'</a>';
buffer += myItem.results[i].description;
buffer += '</p>';
buffer += '</div>';
buffer += '</div>';
buffer += '</div>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = buffer;
//var elem = div.firstChild;
Item.appendChild(div);
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');
btn.value = "Delete";
btn.onclick = (function(i) {
  return function() {
    var c=confirm('Are you Sure? ');
    if (c==true)
    doDelete(myItem.results[i].item_id);

  };
})(i);
Item.appendChild(btn);
var show_btn=document.createElement('input');
show_btn.setAttribute('type','button');
show_btn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-primary');
show_btn.value="ShowInDetail";
show_btn.onclick=(function(i){
    return function(){
        showInDetail(myItem.results[i]);
        window.location='showInDetail.html';
    };
})(i);
Item.appendChild(show_btn);
var extend_btn=document.createElement('input');
extend_btn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-warning');
extend_btn.setAttribute('type','button');
extend_btn.value="Extend";
extend_btn.onclick=(function(i){
    return function(){
        extendItem(myItem.results[i]);
        window.location='extendItem.html';
    };
})(i);
Item.appendChild(extend_btn);
var bookmark=document.createElement('input');
bookmark.setAttribute('type','button');
bookmark.setAttribute('class','btn btn-primary');
bookmark.value='Bookmark';
bookmark.onclick=(function(i){
    return function(){
          var p={user_id:localStorage.getItem('user_id')};
          window.localStorage.setItem('this_item_id', myItem.results[i].item_id);
          getBookmarks(p, function(d){
            var bk=JSON.stringify(d);
            bk=JSON.parse(bk);
            if(bk.results){
                var l=0;
                for(var j in bk.results){
                    if(bk.results[j].item_id==localStorage.getItem('this_item_id')){
                        removeBookmark(bk.results[j]);
                        l=1;
                    }
                }if(l==0){
                        addBookmark(myItem.results[i]);
                    }

            }else{
                addBookmark(myItem.results[i]); 
            }           
          });
    };

})(i);
Item.appendChild(bookmark);
//document.getElementById(i).appendChild(btn);
 }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an example (JS Fiddle, maybe?) that reproduces the problem?  The massive code dump is not particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

In what specific div do you want them? So far, in this way the four buttons are inside the myItens div see in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psouki/hzcympk7/5/) and in the code below.

```
var getmyItems = function(data) {
    var item = document.getElementById('myItems');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var result = data[i];

        // creation of the buffer outer div
        var buffer = document.createElement('div');
        buffer.className = 'act-time';

        //creation of de activity-body
        var activity = document.createElement('div');
        activity.className = 'activity-body act-in';

        //creation of the first span
        var arrow = document.createElement('span');
        arrow.className = 'arrow';

        //creation of the most inner div
        var textDiv = document.createElement('div');
        textDiv.className = 'text';

        //creation of the content of the most inner div
        var attribution = '';
        attribution += '<p class="attribution">';
        attribution += '<a href="#">' + result.title + '</a>';
        attribution += result.description;
        attribution += '</p>';

        //initialize the text div
        textDiv.innerHTML = attribution;

        //put the arrow span inside the activity div
        activity.appendChild(arrow);

        // put the text div inside the activity div
        activity.appendChild(textDiv);

        //put the activity inside the buffer div
        // each time appendChild is applied the element is attach tho the end of the target element
        buffer.appendChild(activity);

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(buffer);
        item.appendChild(div);

        var btn = document.createElement('input');
        btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');
        btn.value = "Delete";
        btn.onclick = (function(i) {
            return function() {
                var c = confirm('Are you Sure? ');
                if (c === true) {
                    //do something;
                };
            };
        })(i);

        // now that all div are created you can choose which div you want to put the button inside.
        // in this I chose the buffer.
        buffer.appendChild(btn);

        var showBtn = document.createElement('input');
        showBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        showBtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
        showBtn.value = "ShowInDetail";
        showBtn.onclick = (function(i) {
            return function() {
                window.location = 'showInDetail.html';
                //do something
            };
        })(i);
        // button is append to the end of the buffer
        buffer.appendChild(showBtn);

        var extendBtn = document.createElement('input');
        extendBtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-warning');
        extendBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        extendBtn.value = "Extend";
        extendBtn.onclick = (function(i) {
            return function() {
                window.location = 'extendItem.html';
                //do something
            };
        })(i);
        // button is append to the end of the buffer
        buffer.appendChild(extendBtn);

        var bookmark = document.createElement('input');
        bookmark.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        bookmark.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
        bookmark.value = 'Bookmark';
        bookmark.onclick = (function(i) {
            return function() {
                var p = { user_id: localStorage.getItem('user_id') };
                window.localStorage.setItem('this_item_id', myItem.results[i].item_id);
                //do something
            };

        })(i);
        // button is append to the end of the buffer
        buffer.appendChild(bookmark);
    }
};
var myItem = [{ title: 'person', description: 'familyName' }, { title: 'ohterPerson', description: 'otherFamilyName' }];
getmyItems(myItem);
```

Comment: I want to put the 4 buttons inside buffer. How can I do that?
Because in this case these buttons are outside of buffer and they are not styled well.

Comment: Instead of appending it to item, append it to the new div created as shown in code above that I updated. Now the four buttons are in the act-time div, if you want to put in a dipper div, just select it and use the appendChild as shown in the code. I hope it helps.

Comment: what is the difference between my code and yours?
In both cases, I and you wrote, all 4 buttons are outside "<div class="act-time">". As I mentioned, I want to style them properly.

Comment: I’ve changed the approach for demonstrations propose. Now I’ve created each div element and built to construct the buffer and later I've chosen which div I want to put the buttons in.  In your code you are appending these buttons in the myItems div, which is why they are out of the buffer.